# How to make a query that uses != in firestore

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

I tried to make my query as it is in the code below but apparently the condition != does not work in firestore react native, can someone give me a hand ?

```
const getUsers = async () => {
        const querySnap = await firestore().collection('users').where('email', '!=', user.email).get()
        const allUsers = querySnap.docs.map(docSnap => docSnap.data())
        console.log(allUsers)
        setUsers(allUsers)
    }
```

Comment: can u define not working? can u check if `user.email` is defined?

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial yes the user.email is set. I get the following error:
FIRESTORE (4.8.0) INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Unknown relation: !=

Comment: From [searching for that error message](https://www.google.com/search?q=ASSERTION+FAILED%3A+Unknown+relation%3A+!%3D) it seems like you may be on a version of the SDK that doesn't support the operator yet. If that's indeed the cause, upgrading to the latest SDK should make the problem go awai.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @FrankvanPuffelen mentioned, the error may be related to your SDK version that doesn't support the `!=` operator.

Try [updating](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/components/update) the SDK in order to solve the issue.